# How to move elements on mouse scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my html and css code snippet:

```css
.clouds {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1200x1200');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
}
.cloud-1 {
  width: 138px;
  height: 83px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 350px;
}
.cloud-2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 52px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 625px;
  top: 400px;
  background-position: -935px -9px;
}
.cloud-3 {
  width: 110px;
  height: 58px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 450px;
  top: 350px;
  background-position: -1033px -6px;
}
```

```html
<div id="animations">
  <div class="clouds cloud-1"></div>
  <div class="clouds cloud-2"></div>
  <div class="clouds cloud-3"></div>
  <div class="clouds cloud-4"></div>
  <div class="clouds cloud-5"></div>
  <div class="clouds cloud-6"></div>
  <div class="clouds cloud-7"></div>
  <div class="clouds cloud-8"></div>
  <div class="clouds cloud-9"></div>
  <div class="clouds cloud-10"></div>
  <div class="clouds cloud-11"></div>
  <div class="clouds cloud-12"></div>
  <div class="clouds cloud-13"></div>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is to move clouds to the website edges when user scrolls down. My clouds is one image sprite, and each cloud is positioned absolutely. Sorry, but I am new to web development and still need to learn a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is best achieved by Javascript, I think. By using JQuery, this should not be too hard.

---

Check how far you are scrolled, first:

```
var scrollPercent = 100 * $('body').scrollTop() / ($('body).height()
```

that gives you the percentage you've scrolled down. Then, you could do something like:

```
$('.cloud-1').css('left', (200 / scrollPercent) + 'px');
```

That will set the image `200 px` from left at the start, towards `2 px` to the left if the user is down the page.

Update those values on scroll:

```
$('body').on('scroll', function(){ 
     // methods described above here 
}
```

---

***note***

The code is not tested, its a heads up in the right direction. Adjust to your needs, and check out the [jquery](http://learn.jquery.com/) docs.

Answer (score 0):

your code snippet is not working to me (because you used relative path to your image...) but you should probably do it like that (replace the height with the height the user has to scroll)

JQuery :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {  
    var scr = $(window).scrollTop();
    var height = 300px;
    if(scr > height) {
       $(document.body).addClass('fix-clouds'); /* add the class on scroll */
    } else {
       $(document.body).removeClass('fix-clouds'); /* remove when we go back to top */
    }
});
```

CSS :

```
.fix-clouds clouds {
    your CSS
}
```

Comment: Thank's mates! This will give me an idea on where to look further.